# QGIS 3.0.3 - Shift when saving image from Google Satellite as VRT

Tags: qgis, raster, vrt

I tried to save Google satellite images with "save as", using VRT option, and setting up the correct resolution. Everything works but the resulting image is slightly shifted to the north, about 3 meters.
All projections are ok, and I noticed when I don't use VRT but a plain image, the shift diappears.
I tried to check all I could think of, to no avail.

Has anyone any idea?

[image: Here a field where the road appears clearly shifted between the correct image on the right and the saved VRT on the left.]